# Call Duration field of Task object throwing error Illegal assignment from Double to Integer

Tags: apex, metadata, tasks

I am parsing all the number fields as **Double.valueOf(value)** and storing in Task fields. If the value is Integer then the result of Double.valueOf(value) will be  **value.0** which is obvious. 
This case is working for all other custom number field even if the precision is given as Number(8,0) but for field **CallDurationInSeconds(number()) I am getting exception Illegal assignment from Double to Integer.**

I am not sure why CallDurationInSeconds is handled separately.

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know CallDurationInSeconds actually stores int, not double, unlike all the other number fields in Salesforce. Not sure why it's made this way though.

Here's some documentation on it:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

I found no other place it says anything about storing integer there though.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find Double.parseDouble(value) in double class definition and when i used this i got this error:-
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void parseDouble(Integer) from the type Double

so, i used valueOf(stringToDouble) which
Returns a Double that contains the value of the specified String. As in Java, the String is interpreted as representing a signed decimal.

Illegal assignment from Double to Integer because You may be storing the double value in Integer variable.May be somehow like this:-

```
Task allTasks = [select id,CallDurationInSeconds from task limit 1 ];
system.debug(allTasks);
allTasks.CallDurationInSeconds=8;
update allTasks;
Integer d=double.valueof(allTasks.CallDurationInSeconds); //throwing the same exception
system.debug(d);
```

But when i tried with double variable it does not throw any exception:-

```
Task allTasks = [select id,CallDurationInSeconds from task limit 1 ];
system.debug(allTasks);
allTasks.CallDurationInSeconds=8;
update allTasks;
double d=double.valueof(allTasks.CallDurationInSeconds); 
system.debug(d);
```

So go to your code, Have a look on which line the exception appears and check for the variable type where you are assigning the double value of CallDurationInSeconds  fields.

Hope it helps you.